# Selecting the 4 closest observations of longitude and latitude from one dataset to a location in another dataset in R

Tags: r, loops, latitude-longitude

I have two datasets. One dataset (a) with 562 observations of village locations by longitude and latitude, the other dataset (b) contains 6400 observations of daily temperatures by longitude and latitude. I would like to find the 4 closest locations of temperature measurements to assign to each village.

I am looking to write a loop to create a third dataset that selects the 4 closest points and their corresponding temperature measurement from the larger dataset b for each village. The same locations can be used more than once if they qualify as the closest location to multiple villages. The final dataset should have 562 * 4 (2,248) observations.

```
head(dataseta)
villageID          lat      lon     
1             10.193657     39.34577   
2             9.028250      38.75095   
3             9.332589      42.13704    
4             9.318443      42.11340       
5             4.485986      40.03652       
6            10.274364      34.93280  


head(datasetb)
  lon     lat   tmax_1
1 0.125  59.875 72.2233
2 0.375  59.875 72.2275
3 0.625  59.875 72.2318
4 0.875  59.875 72.2361
5 1.125  59.875 72.2421
6 1.375  59.875 72.2531
```

Comment: Check out `fuzzyjoin::geo_inner_join`: https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin  That will let you quickly add all the matches that are within a threshold distance, and then you could filter for just the closest for each village.

Comment: Thank you! This worked great :) @JonSpring